# How can I use an attribute from another table in defining a derived attribute in a new table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example: I have a table "Children" which has an attribute "age". I am now making a table "Students" which inherits only the primary key "SSN" from child, but it should have an attribute "grade" which is derived from the corresponding child's age as (Children.age - 5).

This is something I made up and tried that resulted in a syntax error:

> "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

```
create table Children
(
    SSN int, 
    age int, 
    primary key(SSN)
)

create table Students
(
    SSN int, 
    grade as (select C.age from Children C, Students S where C.SSN = S.SSN) - 5, 
    primary key(SSN)
)
```

Even though I know it doesn't make sense because a select query will not necessarily return an int value and because it doesn't make sense to use a table in a subquery that I have not yet created, but I thought I'd add it here to see if maybe there is some sort of way to use a subquery that would work similar to this manner I attempted.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Create both tables normally and then use a view to join both tables and create a virtual column for the grade.

For example:

```
Select c.*, s.*, (c.age - 5) as grade from children c
Inner join student s on s.childid = c.id
```

Comment: In the time it took me to write my answer, Thorsten captured the essence of what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW Students AS
  SELECT c.*,
         Grade = c.age - 5
    FROM Children c
```